# Joomla 1.6.3 and 1.6.4 -> Impossible to change the template

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6, joomla-template

In Joomla 1.6.3 (upgraded for now to 1.6.4), at a point I could not change the template (though the right one was well-selected into the Mysql database).

It's on **[www.creasixtine.fr](http://www.creasixtine.fr)**.

It tells me now this :

> Notice: Undefined index: 116 in /homez.428/creasixt/sites/creasixtine.fr/includes/application.php on line 458
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /homez.428/creasixt/sites/creasixtine.fr/includes/application.php on line 461
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$params in /homez.428/creasixt/sites/creasixtine.fr/includes/application.php on line 243
>
> Erreur
>
> Le template nécessaire à cet affichage est indisponible. Veuillez contacter un administrateur du site.

So I wonder what goes bad and why I cannot change the template...

Comment: Workaround -> I reinstalled totally Joomla... As I just had installed it, it is no big time loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have suggested copying the 1.6.3 -> 1.6.4 upgrade package onto your server again. There must have been a corrupt file when you did it initially.